# How to create a scoreboard for my tennis game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm creating a tennis game with `Pygame` and Python (obviously). I am trying to implement a scoreboard so that when the ball stops, assuming the other player cannot reach it, the score goes up.

I've tried using an `if` statement checking if the ball's speed has stopped, but that just pretty much created a running clock. I also don't need the score to go up while the ball is stopped in its starting position (haven't added serving mechanics yet).

```py
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
OUT = (193, 58, 34)
COURT = (69, 150, 81)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
SKIN = (232, 214, 162)

ballspeed = 2

# Create the screen
windowsize = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(windowsize)
pygame.display.set_caption('Tennis')

# Player Sprites
class Robert(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Robert_tennis.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (360, 480)
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -4
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 4
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > 700:
            self.rect.right = 700
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 3
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.y < 235:
            self.rect.y = 235
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0

class Camden(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("camden_tennis_front.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (360, 100)
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.speedx = -6
        if keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speedx = 6
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > 700:
            self.rect.right = 700
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if keystate[pygame.K_w]:
            self.speedy = -7
        if keystate[pygame.K_s]:
            self.speedy = 5
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.y > 180:
            self.rect.y = 180
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("tennisball.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (360, 325)
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        #Robert's forehand
        if tennisball.rect.colliderect(robert) and tennisball.rect.x > robert.rect.x + 10:
            robert.image = pygame.image.load("Robert_tennis2 (1).png")
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound('tennisserve.wav')
            effect.play(0)
            robert.rect.y -5
            self.speedy = -8
            self.speedx = 4

        #Robert's forehand volley
        if tennisball.rect.colliderect(robert) and tennisball.rect.x > robert.rect.x + 10 and robert.rect.y < 300:
            robert.image = pygame.image.load("Robert_tennis.png")
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound('tennisserve.wav')
            effect.play(0)
            robert.rect.y -5
            self.speedy = -3
            self.speedx = -3

        #Robert's backhand
        if tennisball.rect.colliderect(robert) and tennisball.rect.x < robert.rect.x - 10:
            robert.image = pygame.image.load("Robert_tennis2_backhand.png")
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound('tennisserve.wav')
            effect.play(0)
            robert.rect.y -5
            self.speedy = -7
            self.speedx = -3

        #Robert's backhand volley
        if tennisball.rect.colliderect(robert) and tennisball.rect.x < robert.rect.x - 10 and robert.rect.y < 300:
            robert.image = pygame.image.load("Robert_tennis_backhand_volley.png")
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound('tennisserve.wav')
            effect.play(0)
            robert.rect.y -5
            self.speedy = -3
            self.speedx = -3

        #Camden's forehand
        if tennisball.rect.colliderect(camden) and tennisball.rect.x < camden.rect.x -10:
            camden.image = pygame.image.load("camden_front_forehand.png")
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound('tennisserve.wav')
            effect.play(0)
            camden.rect.y -5
            self.speedy = 9
            self.speedx = 2

        self.speedy = self.speedy * .98
        self.speedx = self.speedx * .96
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speedx, self.speedy)

#Add people
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
robert = Robert()
camden = Camden()
tennisball = Ball()
all_sprites.add(robert)
all_sprites.add(tennisball)
all_sprites.add(camden)

carryOn = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

global score
score = 0

screen.fill(OUT)


while carryOn:
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    scorebox = font.render(str(score), True, WHITE, BLACK)
    scoreRect = scorebox.get_rect()
    scoreRect.center = (625, 50)
    screen.blit(scorebox, scoreRect)
    if tennisball.speedx == 0 and tennisball.speedy == 0 and tennisball.rect.x != 360 and tennisball.rect.y != 325:
        score = score + 1
        scorebox = font.render(str(score), True, WHITE, BLACK)
        scoreRect.center = (625, 50)
        screen.blit(scorebox, scoreRect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                carryOn = False

    all_sprites.update()

    # Fill the screen with a sky color

    # Draw the court
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, COURT, [175, 0, 350, 500])
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (170,500), (170,0), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (520,500), (520,0), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (170,130), (520,130), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (170,370), (520,370), 10)
    #center line
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (345,130), (345,370), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (170,250), (520,250), 10)

    # Update
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

I expect the score to update when the ball stops. I can worry about resetting the ball when I implement serving mechanics later.

Comment: @Rabbid76 not exactly. it scores when the ball starts, and won’t score after

Answer (score 1):

Since the the position attributes of the tennis ball are floating point values, the never get exactly 0.0, but the get a value very close to 0.0.
You have to do a [Epsilon Comparison](https://wiki.cs.astate.edu/index.php/Epsilon_Comparison):

Test if `tennisball.speedx` and `tennisball.speedy` are close to 0.0by checking if the absolut value ([`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)) is less than a certain threshold (epsilon):

```py
abs(tennisball.speedx) < espi and abs(tennisball.speedy) < espi:
```

Change the term `tennisball.speedx == 0 and tennisball.speedy == 0` in yuor code:

```py
espi = 0.1
if abs(tennisball.speedx) < espi  and abs(tennisball.speedy) < espi:
    score = score + 1
```

Note, you've to "choose" the value of `epsi` for your needs.

---

> [...] but that just pretty much created a running clock.

Add a state `allow_score` which indicates if it is allowed to score and initialize it by `False`:

```py
allow_score = False
```

Immediately when the ball starts to moving, then state has to be signaled (`allow_score = True`). From now on it is possible to score.
When the ball has stopped and `allow_score == True`, then it is possible to score, but it is only possible to score once, so the state has to be be reset (`allow_score = False`).
This cause that the score is not continuously increases, because to score again, the ball has to move first:

```py
while carryOn:

    # [...]

    moving = abs(tennisball.speedx) > espi or abs(tennisball.speedy) > espi 
    if moving:
        allow_score = True 
    elif allow_score:
        allow_score = False
        score = score + 1
```

Note, since `allow_score` is initialized `False`, the score is not incremented at the start.

Comment: Thank you. Will try it later. Thanks for checking back